# 403 Forbidden even though FollowSymLinks is enabled

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, subdomain

I have a vanilla apache2 server installed on a Debian 7 vps. Within the `sites-enabled` folder, I created a file for a particular subdomain. It is working and shows the correct files at the correct document root, but I get 403 Forbidden errors on any static resources the index.html page requests. My configuration file is below:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName foo.bar.net
            ServerAlias foo.bar.net
            DocumentRoot /home/foobar/someLibary/demo
            <Directory /home/foobar/someLibary/demo>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

            # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, cric, alert, emerg.
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Paste relevant error log output and file permissions of `/home/foobar/someLibary/demo`

Answer (score 4):

What is in the error logs?

Have you also checked permissions on the files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be obeying this virtualhost if you don't have NameVirtualHost directive defined. In which case your system defaults would be in effect.

Try running httpd -S and see if the output makes sense, it should describe your virtualhosts.